# Where can I find a screen (terminal multiplexer) that was created and detached with a startup-script? (GCP)

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, startupscript

I am using GCP to run a game server and added a startup script to the VM to automatically run the gameserver in a screen, so if needed I can access the console to the server by re-attaching, the screen is starting and I am able to connect to the server so I know its their but I cannot find the screen using `screen -ls`

My startup script is:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /home/minecraft
screen -dm java -Xmx3G -Xms2G -jar ./BTeam.jar nogui
```

After running `screen -ls` to find the screen to re-attach to it says there are no sockets to attach to.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to find screen running if you run

```
ps aux | grep -i screen
```

If so, please post the ENTIRE line that results from it (that isn't "grep -i screen")

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, just shows the grep -i screen process, is it possible that the screen isn't running and that it just ran the command normally?

Comment: I am however able to see the java process using `ps aux | grep -i java` it shows as `root       745 25.0 29.9 5733072 1365712 ?     Sl   15:33  12:36 java -Xmx3G -Xms2G -jar ./BTeam.jar nogui`

Comment: if you were to start screen, initiate your java process and then 'Ctrl-a  d' Do you see it then?

Comment: It seems that the screen was not running in the startup script, which is odd. Not sure why it isn’t running I am going to give it a shot using a different multiplexer

Comment: Could you solve your issue asterisk? If you did please put it as an answer so it could help other people.